# Getting rid anything outside curly braces

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex in php that allows the following:

here is the given example
1. aaa aaa{bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}xxx
2. 123{asd{asd{asd{asd}asd}}asd}qwe

the output will be:
1. {bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}
2. {asd{asd{asd{asd}asd}}asd}

I tried this but does not work

```
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $resonse, $matches);
```

its basically getting rid of anything outside the main curly braces eventhought there are curly braces inside of it. I really need you help. thanks so much.

Comment: i tried this but does not work 
preg_match_all('/{(.*?)}/', $resonse, $matches);

i need the whole main curly braces section

Comment: Okay, I updated your question for you.  Please bear in mind that normally on Stack Overflow you're expected to have shown that you tried to solve the problem yourself, people here are glad to help out with problems you're having but they're not so happy to help out if it looks like you're just asking people to do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks GordonM, im kinda new here.

Comment: That's okay, we were all new once. :)  I'm sure you'll do fine once you have a better understanding of the etiquette here.  May I suggest that you review the FAQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need PCRE's recursion capabilities to do this.

```
<?php
$pattern = '!
  { # patterns start with curly brace
      (?:           # ?: means that this is only for grouping, not for capturing
                    # the { } contain 
        [^{}]*      # not-curly-braces-characters
      |             # or
        (?R)        # this pattern again, i.e. {^[{}] | (?R) } again
      )*
  } # patterns ends with curly brace
!x';

foreach( array('aaa aaa{bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}xxx', '123{asd{asd{asd{asd}asd}}asd}qwe') as $subject ) {
    echo "\n$subject: ";
    if ( preg_match($pattern, $subject, $m) ) {
        echo $m[0];
    }
    else {
        echo '--no match--';
    }
}
```

prints

```
aaa aaa{bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}xxx: {bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}
123{asd{asd{asd{asd}asd}}asd}qwe: {asd{asd{asd{asd}asd}}asd}
```

Comment: I like the explanation of each pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex at all:

```
$str = 'aaa aaa{bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}xxx';

$replace = substr(substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '}') + 1), strpos($str, '{'));

echo $replace; // displays "{bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}"
```

If you'd benchmark this code it'd probably turn out much faster than regex. You shouldn't use something complex for something so simple.

I figured you might want to match multiple results per-string. In that case, I still probably have a faster solution that doesn't rely on any modules:

```
$str = 'aaa aaa{bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}xxxaaa qaaa{bb b {cqwe cc}{d cdd}e qweee}xxx';
$array = str_split($str);
$opens = 0;
$result = '';

$results = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if($array[$i] === '{') {
        $opens++;
    } else if($array[$i] === '}' && $opens > 0) {
        $opens--;
    }

    if($opens > 0) $result .= $array[$i];

    if($opens === 0 && strlen($result) > 0) {
        $results[] = $result . '}';
        $result = '';
    }
}

print_r($results);

/*
results:
Array
(
    [0] => {bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}
    [1] => {bb b {cqwe cc}{d cdd}e qweee}
)

*/
```

Comment: Yes ...unless you only want to consider balanced braces or put more constraints on the `aaa bb b` part . I somehow implied that.

Comment: The second method I posted does supports this and can match multiple results in a string.

Comment: Yes so very true, this is indeed be useful for multiple instances. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str = "abc{def{ghi{jkl}mno{pqr}st}uvw}xyz" ;

$str = preg_match("#\{((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*\}#x", $str, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE, 3);

print_r($matches);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do it: `preg_replace('/(^[^{]*)|([^}]*$)/', '', 'aaa aaa{bb b {c cc}{d dd}e ee}xxx');`

Comment: I tried this code also, its simple and it works, thanks very much for this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this really a job for a regex?  It would appear easier to just grab the substring you want by looking for the first `{` and the last `}`.  For example, this:

```php
$str = "abc {kjlj { jkljlkj } ljkj } kljlj";

$start = strpos($str, '{');  # First {
$end = strrpos($str, '}');   # Last }

$section = substr($str, $start, $end - $start + 1);
echo $section;  # => "{kjlj { jkljlkj } ljkj }"
```

Comment: yes not really, the first thing that struck my mind is regex. and yes you are correct, substr can also be used. this is also a very good method as well, but i was thinking of any other way the results can be changed or expand in a way. thanks for the help.

Comment: No problem.  Regexes are very useful and I love them, but it's always worthwhile to consider alternatives :)